# C# - Intersecting two different custom lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two different lists of objects that I want to intersect, so I create a wrapper object for my different custom objects where I store a compare variable and implement IEquatable so I can run the LINQ intersect function.

For some reason I can't get the result that I want with this, just giving me null returns. It's not hitting my breakpoint in the equals function either. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? It's probably something simple.

```
internal class CompareObject : IEquatable<CompareObject>
{
    public CompareObject(customClass myParentObject) 
    {
        this.myParentObject = myParentObject;
        this.compareString = myParentObject.customCompareField;
    }
    public string compareString { get; set; }
    public object myParentObject { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CompareObject? other)
    {
        return this.compareString == other.compareString;
    }
}
internal class CompareObjectA : CompareObject
{
    public CompareObjectA(customClassA myParentObject)
    {
        this.myParentObject = myParentObject;
        this.compareString = myParentObject.customCompareField;
    }
}
internal class CompareObjectB : CompareObject
{
    public CompareObjectB(customClassB myParentObject)
    {
        this.myParentObject = myParentObject;
        this.compareString = myParentObject.customCompareField;
    }
}
public void Execute()
    {
        var listA = new List<CompareObjectA>(<<SAMPLE VALUES>>);
        var listB = new List<CompareObjectB>(<<SAMPLE VALUES>>);

        var listC = listA.Select(a => (CompareObject)a).Intersect(listB.Select(a => ((CompareObject)a));
    }
```

Comment: Override GetHashCode and return compareString.GetHashCode()

Comment: Simple `Join` will make intersection and there is no need to play with `IEquatable`

Comment: I'd advise against this approach (regardless if you make it work or not). Instead, implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<YourClass>` and provide the implementation when calling `Intersect` (there is an overload that takes that as an argument).

Comment: See also [IEquatable<T> Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) and especially [Notes to Implementers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-7.0#notes-to-implementers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.Intersect` is a set based method which is not a linear search, so it doesn't use just `Equals` to compare two objects. Instead it uses first `GetHashCode`. In general you should always override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` together, so also if you implement `IEquatable<T>`;

```
public override bool Equals(object? obj)
{
    return obj is CompareObject obj2 && this.Equals(obj2);
}

public bool Equals(CompareObject? other)
{
    return this.compareString == other?.compareString;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return compareString.GetHashCode();
}
```

Note that you have to use `Intersect` in this way:

```
var listC = listA.Intersect(listB).ToList();
```

Another approach to provide a custom comparer for a class is to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` which requires to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
public class CompareStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<CompareObject>
{
    public bool Equals(CompareObject x, CompareObject y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return x.compareString == y.compareString;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CompareObject obj)
    {
        return obj.compareString.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You can use this comparer for many LINQ methods, also for `Intersect`:

```
var listC = listA.Intersect(listB, new CompareStringComparer()).ToList();
```

You'd use this approach if you have multiple ways to compare the object or if you can't or don't want to modify the class itself.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to just write:

```
var result = a.IntersectBy(b, x => x.compareString);
```

Comment: This really looks super clean, but it's giving me a type error for some reason. Troubleshooting a bit to see if I can get it working.

Comment: I believe it was introduces in .NET 6 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-7.0